# Is there a way using runas command to remotely connect to SQL Server (external domain) and try debugging production code (internal domain)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, iis-8

I am setting up a process and environment to debug production issues. The problem we have is that the developers are contractors (different domain) and use Visual Studio to connect to our SQL Server databases (in our domain). We are facing connection issues in code.

**Tried**: while we are able to launch Visual Studio using `runas /netonly` switch, but while debugging, the database is not connected. Please refer to the **attached diagram below** for better understanding.

**Error**:

> Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server
>   An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1326

[image]

Comment: First try connecting as a SQL User, not a windows user. If this works, then that is a pragmatic workaround. If it doesn't work then you have a non-security issue that you need to resolve first. Note that your error doesn't mention authentication at all

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : actually we do not want a single generic SQL User to be shared by the entire team(the contractor team, company ABC), we want to give only few of the contractors(users created in our domain) permission via company Company XYZ VPN so that we can track or analyze who is doing what

Comment: Understood. First try it and determine whether it is an authorization issue or not. Have you ever been able to connect?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : let me share the complete error. 

An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.  When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1326

Comment: Please edit the question and include the entire error. Note again this is not an authentication error. It’s a generic connectivity error.

Comment: The driver falling back to named pipes is a sure sign that you've got a more basic connectivity problem, likely nothing to do with credentials. Verify the server is actually reachable through TCP/IP on port 1433 from those VPN machines. Also check for DNS mismatches, if the machines don't use your domain's name services. You can force the use of TCP/IP only by prefixing the server name with the `tcp:` protocol override so you don't get confusing errors about named pipes. If the machine is reachable, but logging in fails, it will tell you that (rather than "timeout expired").

Comment: @Jeroen: while we look into this   — below Microsoft article mentions couple of other things along with TCP 1433 port opening, do we require to enable all described options and do you feel any vulnerable issues? https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/914277/how-to-configure-sql-server-2005-to-allow-remote-connections